# How do you solve this proof by induction question?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

a)Show that $\dfrac{1}{3r-1}  - \dfrac{1}{3r+2}  = \dfrac{3}{(3r-1)(3r+2)}$

b)hence show that $\sum\limits^{2n}_{r=1} \dfrac{1}{(3r-1)(3r+2)} = \dfrac{n}{2(3n+1)}$

How does one do part b?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference&ved=2ahUKEwi63KjuhsXpAhVSeX0KHWiBAD8QFjAAegQIBBAC&usg=AOvVaw1zLdIXv6Cu4GY53kDgHoTt) for writing mathematical terms.

Comment: What do you mean with $\equiv$?

Comment: I copied the question, it was  ≡ and not =

Comment: Is it $\frac{1}{3r-1}$ or $\frac{1}{3r}-1$?

Comment: @OP Check that my edit is correct.

Comment: I uploaded a picture, sorry

Comment: Pictures should not be used unless absolutely necessary.  Keep it as MathJax.

Comment: In any event... series like this will [telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).  If you try expanding it out using the replacement proven in part (a), you will find many of the terms will cancel with one another. except for maybe the first term(s) and the last term(s).  Here, you have something like $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{11}-\frac{1}{14}+\dots$.  Clearly, the $\frac{1}{5}$'s cancel and the $\frac{1}{8}$'s cancel, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove part b, first note that $n_0=1$ satisfies the equality. Then, assume that the equality holds for $n$.
$$ \sum_{r=1}^{2(n+1)} \frac{1}{(3r-1)(3r+2)} = \sum_{r=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{(3r-1)(3r+2)} + \sum_{r=2n+1}^{2n+2} \frac{1}{(3r-1)(3r+2)} = \frac{n}{2(3n+1)} +  \frac{1}{(3(2n+1)-1)(3(2n+1)+2)} + \frac{1}{(3(2n+2)-1)(3(2n+2)+2)} $$
After some calculations, you will find that this is equal to
$$ \frac{n+1}{2(3(n+1)+1)} $$
concluding the induction.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand perfectly now

Answer (score 1):

So you do not have to prove this using Mathematical Induction itself. It is actually pretty easier than that.

So from (a) you have one result which gives you:

$\sum_{r=1}^{2n}[\frac{1}{3r-1}-\frac{1}{3r+2}]=\sum_{r=1}^{2n}[\frac{1}{3(r-1)+2}-\frac{1}{3r+2}]$

Hence the sum=$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{8}+...+\frac{1}{6n-4}-\frac{1}{6n-1}+\frac{1}{6n-1}-\frac{1}{6n+2}$, every other term cancel out.

Hence sum=$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{6n+2}=\frac{6n+2-2}{2(6n+2)}=\frac{3n}{2(3n+1)}$

PS: Okay, so I think my steps are correct so can you please check the question again? *nervous chuckle*

Comment: You replaced $\dfrac{\color{red}{1}}{(3r-1)(3r+2)}$ rather than $\dfrac{\color{red}{3}}{(3r-1)(3r+2)}$, hence the discrepancy in your final answer.